# Caching in JavaScript and return values

Tags: javascript

Hi can someone explain the function below? I have added comments to show the limit of my understanding. I'm stuck and don't understanding why we create an emtpy object called result and assign this to myFunc.cache[cachekey]?
Should result store the result of the 'expensive operation'?

```
// call myFunc with a list of parameters
var myFunc = function () {

// store the function params in an array
    var cachekey = JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)),
        result;

// check the cache object for the list of params / string
    if (!myFunc.cache[cachekey]) {
        result = {};
        // ... expensive operation ...
        myFunc.cache[cachekey] = result;
    }
    return myFunc.cache[cachekey];
};

// cache storage
myFunc.cache = {};
```

Comment: "Should result store the result of the 'expensive operation'?" — How should we know? You didn't include the code for that operation.

Comment: Check the cache to see if you already have the result if not get the result. Avoid getting the result if you don't have to because it is expensive.

Comment: *Should result store the result of the 'expensive operation'?* **Yes.** Welcome to the wonderful world of [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Yeap, `result` should be whatever was computed expensively. There's no need for it to be an object or be assigned at that particular place as long as you store whatever interests you inside `myFunc.cache[cachekey]`

Comment: Thanks, all that makes sense